# stop() and start() Methods in main class are called automatically on iOS

Tags: ios, codenameone

My app connects to Facebook and Parse and it works well on simulator and android but it doesn't work on iOS.

The stop() *(the Display.getCurrent() returns my current form)* and start() methods of the main class are always called automatically. This caused my app (current form) disappeared in unexpected way. I thought the application was crashed but not.

When I double tap on the Home button I can see my app and when I select, it starts again. Any idea can help?

Thanks, William

Answer (score 1):

When iOS app crashes or get killed, it doesn't remove the app from the recent apps you see when you double tap home button. It will only restart the app when you open it (Apps usually get killed on iOS within 10 minutes, depending on if the app is using any resources or not).

Verify that your app is indeed not crashing on iOS. Uncomment the crash reporter from the class that contains start() and stop() methods. This will send you an email if the app crashes and if you are a pro or higher CN1 subscriber.

Just for clarification, the class should look similar to this:

```
private Form current;

public void init(Object context) {
    Display.getInstance().addEdtErrorHandler((evt) -> {
        evt.consume();
        Log.p("Exception in MyApp version " + Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppVersion", "1.0"));
        Log.p("OS " + Display.getInstance().getPlatformName());
        Log.p("Error " + evt.getSource());
        Log.p("Current Form " + Display.getInstance().getCurrent().getName());
        Log.e((Throwable) evt.getSource());
        Log.sendLog();
    });
}

public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    new StateMachine("/theme");
}

public void stop() {
    current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
}

public void destroy() {
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense when iOS kills an app if it runs over 10 minutes. I think the app itself is probably crashed if an out of resource or a violation happened. I think the crash-protection feature should be only suitable when the app is in production (published to stores for users to download and use). I don't think it makes sense in development phase.

Comment: So, in development phase, I just write log messages in the body of stop() and start() functions of the main class and in the body of addEdtErrorHandler() event handler to local storage of my test iOS device. The app will check and display these log messages if they are found when starts up next time. By this way, I see my app didn't crash last time (the log message in the body of addEdtErrorHandler() event handler was not written to local storage) while the log messages in the body of stop() and start() functions were written.